# Setter / getter method inheritance

Tags: java

So I was studying about inheritance in java and I didn't get it quite clear. Suppose we have a parent method with a private variable and public setter getter methods. A subclass inherits these methods but not the private variable. Are these methods always connected with the superclass which also runs with the subclass? I can't declare a variable with the same name in the subclass, so inherited method would access it instead. I know doesn't work. Do the setter/getter methods always affect only values in objects where they are declared, even called from a subclass by inheritance?

Comment: You cannot inherit the methods but not the variables. You inherit everything from the parent class. Private just means that you cannot directly access it, but it is still there.

Comment: The private variable doesn't disappear, it's just not accessible to the subclass instance. Accessing it through the superclass getters still works.

Comment: Please keep reading and *trying* inheritance. You could have answered your own question by reading a few guides and opening Eclipse to try it yourself.

Comment: think on subclassing like appending code to a class, maybe this will help you to get the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe an example can help you to understand

```
public class C1 {
    protected int x = 1;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(new C1().getX());
        System.out.println(new C2().getX());
        System.out.println(new C3().getX());
        System.out.println(new C4().getX());
    }

}
```

and

```
public class C2 extends C1{
}
```

and

```
public class C3 extends C2{
    protected int x = 3;
}
```

and

```
public class C4 extends C3{

    protected int x = 4;

    @Override
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

}
```

you'll get

```
C1.x = 1
C2.x = 1
C3.x = 1
C4.x = 4
```

let's see what's happening.

- C1.x is 1 for obvious reasons
- C2.x is 1 because it's just the same as C1
- C3.x is 1 because getX() can see only the "x" declared at C1 (not intuitive for some people)
- C4.x is 4 because getX() is being overridden at C4, so it can see the "x" declared at C4

Answer (score 2):

Say you have a class `A` with a private int variable `a` and a getter `getA()` and a setter `setA(int)`:

```
public class A {
    private int a;
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(int value) {
        a = value;
    }
}
```

Now if you have a class `B` that extends class `A`, you can ensure that the getter and the setter cannot be overridden by a subclass of `B`:

```
public class B extends A {
    @Override
    public final int getA() {
        return super.getA();
    }
    @Override
    public final void setA(int value) {
        super.setA(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will help too:

```
package testvehicle;


public class Car extends Vehicle
{

    private int numDoors;
    private int numWheels;


    public Car(String manufacturer,String model,int maxSpeed,double price,int numWheels
            ,int numDoors)
    {
        super(manufacturer,model,maxSpeed,price);
        this.numDoors=numDoors;
        this.numWheels=numWheels;

    }

    public Car()
    {

    }


    public int getNumDoors()
    {
        return numDoors;
    }


    public void setNumDoors(int numDoors)
    {
        this.numDoors = numDoors;
    }


    public int getNumWheels()
    {
        return numWheels;
    }


    public void setNumWheels(int numWheels)
    {
        this.numWheels = numWheels;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return ("Number of doors:"+numDoors+"\n"+"Number of wheels:"+numWheels+""
                + "\n"+
        "Manufacturer:"+manufacturer+"\n"+
               "Model:"+model+"\n"+"Maximum Speed:"+maxSpeed+"\n"+"Price in euros:"+price+
               "\n");
    }

}



package testvehicle;


public class MotorCycle extends Vehicle
{
    private String seat;

    public MotorCycle(String manufacturer,String model,int maxSpeed,double price
            ,String seat)
    {
        super( manufacturer, model, maxSpeed, price);
        this.seat=seat;
    }


    public MotorCycle()
    {

    }


    public String getSeat()
    {
        return seat;
    }


    public void setSeat(String seat)
    {
        this.seat = seat;
    }


    public String toString()
    {
        return ("Manufacturer:"+manufacturer+"\n"+
               "Model:"+model+"\n"+"Maximum Speed:"+maxSpeed+"\n"+"Price in euros:"+price+
               "\n"+"Seat type:"+seat+"\n");
    }




}



 package testvehicle;

    public abstract class Vehicle//This class doesn't do something!
    {
        protected String manufacturer;
        protected String model;
        protected int maxSpeed;
        protected double price;

        public Vehicle(String manufacturer,String model,int maxSpeed,double price)
        {
            this.manufacturer=manufacturer;
            this.model=model;
            this.maxSpeed=maxSpeed;
            this.price=price;

        }

        public Vehicle()
        {

        }


        public String getManufacturer()
        {
            return manufacturer;
        }


        public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer)
        {
            this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        }


        public String getModel()
        {
            return model;
        }


        public void setModel(String model)
        {
            this.model = model;
        }


        public int getMaxSpeed()
        {
            return maxSpeed;
        }


        public void setMaxSpeed(int maxSpeed)
        {
            this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
        }


        public double getPrice()
        {
            return price;
        }


        public void setPrice(double price)
        {
            this.price = price;
        }



       public String toString()
        {
           return ("Manufacturer:"+manufacturer+"\n"+
                   "Model:"+model+"\n"+"Maximum Speed:"+maxSpeed+"\n"+"Price in euros:"+price+
                   "\n");
        }



    }

    package testvehicle;

    public class Main
    {


        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Car C=new Car("Opel","Corsa",220,12000.0,4,5);
            MotorCycle M=new MotorCycle("KTM","DUKE-690",250,9000.0,"Agressive");
            System.out.println(C.toString());
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(M.toString());

        }


    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Sub-classes inherit both methods and public variables.  They don't inherit private variables.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: This is simply not accurate. Both methods and variables (fields) have visibility restrictions. The subclass can always access (see) protected and public and may (if in same package) access default scoped.

Comment: Wrong. Sub-classes inherit **everything**. Including everything with the private modifier such as private methods and variables. Private methods and variables are simply not accessable in sub-classes, but that does **not** mean that they are not there.

Comment: @1337 pedantically not true.  Subclasses do not inherit constructors.

Comment: @emory Well, of course, but I was referring to methods, variables, .. :)